# Add-Migration with seeds throwing "no value provided" exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to create a package that will help seed databases with data from JSON files which can be created manually or extracted from a legacy database. Currently I have created a generic class `SeedCreator<T>` which retrieves JSON from a given file (the name of the entity plus `.json`) and deserialises it into an object of the given type. This part is working fine.

To make this process as dynamic as possible I am using reflection on the entities in the project by identifying all classes with the namespace `Entities`. With this, I am looping through the retrieved `List` and checking if the JSON file exists. If it does I pass the path and the generic type to the class `SeedsCreator`. When debugging whilst running `Add-Migration`, the data comes back as I'd expect from the JSON file but after the variable `modelBuilder` gets returned I get the error `The seed entity for entity type 'Table1' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Id'.`

If I manually put in the following it works fine.

```
modelBuilder.Entity(typeof(Table1)).HasData(data);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Especially if I'm blind and have done something very simple and stupid.

```
public class Seeds
{
    public ModelBuilder CreateSeeds(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entities = (from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                       where t.Namespace != null && (t.IsClass && t.Namespace.Contains("Entities"))
                       select t).ToList();

        foreach (var type in entities)
        {
            if (File.Exists("./Seeds/" + type.Name + ".json"))
            {
                Type[] typeArr = { type };
                var seeds = typeof(SeedCreator<>).MakeGenericType(typeArr);
                var activatedSeeds = Activator.CreateInstance(seeds);
                var data = seeds.GetMethod("GetSeeds")?.Invoke(activatedSeeds, new object[] { "./Seeds/" + type.Name + ".json" });
                modelBuilder.Entity(type).HasData(data);
            }
        }

        return modelBuilder;
    }
}

public class SeedCreator<T>
{
    public List<T> GetSeeds(string jsonPath)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(jsonPath))
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}

public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the DbContext

```
using (var dataSeed = new Seeds()) modelBuilder = dataSeed.CreateSeeds(modelBuilder);
```

Example JSON file (`Table1.json`)

```
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

Stack trace

`` System.InvalidOperationException: The seed entity for entity type 'Table1' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Id'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateData(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ValidatingConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action) ``

Comment: Your JSON file (or at least what you wrote here) has `id` whereas your model has `Id`. Could it be that simple?

Comment: The JsonConvert deserialises camelCase into classes fine. I will update the question in just a second to show what works

Comment: @Pierre-LoupPagniez just tried it to confirm and it doesn't change anything. I was hoping it wasn't that simple.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are falling into typical `params object[]` trap.

The `HasData` method has 2 overloads - one with `params object[] data` and one with `IEnumerable<object> data`. Due to the reflection call, the type of your `data` variable is `object`. Hence you are calling the first overload with *single* item `object[]` containing your `data`.

If you are wondering why the exception message is telling you that no value is provided for a property, the explanation is simple. `HasData` does not require the passed objects to be of the same type as the entity being seeded. This is to allow specifying the shadow properties which does not exist in the entity class, but are required for data seeding. So it allows you to pass any anonymous or concrete type which contains all the entity properties.

Hence it's trying to reflect the actual type of the passed objects and find a property `Id`. Since the actual type of the passed single object in your case is `List<TEntity>`, of course it has no `Id` property, hence the exception message.

With all that being said, the fix is of course to call the correct `HasData` overload (with `IEnumerable<object> data`):

```
modelBuilder.Entity(type).HasData((IEnumerable<object>)data);
```

Comment: You sir, are a legend amongst men. Thank you so much.

Comment: Imagine the fun you'd get from running the code if `List<TEntity>` *had* the `Id` property.

Comment: This was it, thanks! I don't know why the `params object[] data` overload was being called when I was passing 3 arrays of a known type, so it should have called the `params TEntity[] data` overload?

Comment: @ShahinDohan There is no `params TEntity[]` overload AFAIK. And if you are passing 3 *arrays*, you definitely are hitting `params object[]`. `params` basically allows you call a method w/o explicitly allocating array, i.e. `Foo(arg1, arg2, .., argN)` vs `Foo(new [] { arg1, arg2, ..., argN) }`

Comment: @IvanStoev Actually there is an overload like that, at least in EF Core 3.1. But you're right about the arrays, of course it will choose the object overload, because `params TEntity[]` takes multiple `TEntity`, not multiple arrays of `TEntity`... I guess I was too tired :)